# CKEditor adding <p> tags after <div> created using editor.insertElement

Tags: ckeditor

I am developing a plugin for CKEditor 3 and whenever I insert an element of type div, it automatically inserts `<p> </p>`  tags after the closing `</div>` tag.

i.e.

```
<div class="a">
    ....
</div>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

I don't want it to add the `<p> </p>` tags at the end. Is there a way to do this without modifying the config.js file?

The plugin.js code is:

```
aDiv = editor.document.createElement('div');
aDiv.setAttribute('class', 'a');
aDiv.setText('...');
editor.insertElement(aDiv);
```